# mysql server returns wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, date

this is strange, I looked around a lot, anybody can confirm it is mysql server bug?

MySQL table has ID and Date fields more than 200 records and dates vary, few of them are today's date!

This query:

```
SELECT id, MAX(date_format('date', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')) AS mymaxdate 
from mytable1
```

Returns wrong date! something like 10 days back...

While using this:

```
SELECT id, max('date') AS mymaxdate from mytable1
```

Works ok, BUT, returns the date in yyyy-mm-dd g:i:a

My need is simple, to select the mlatest "max" date in dd-mm-yyyy

Anybody faced this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're taking the MAX() of a **STRING**. Since you've got your day value first:

```
'31-01-1900' > '01-01-2014'
```

is true, because `31` > `01`.

You probably want

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(MAX(date), '%....')
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the `MAX()` of a formatted date sorted by day number, then month, then year. Sorting on this will produce out of order results.

What you need to do is move the formatting to PHP, not MySQL. Your database should be concerned primarily with *data*. PHP can handle rewriting the data to suit your presentation needs using something like [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).